# Generate hierarchical path

Tags: oracle, select, oracle-12c, window-functions, hierarchy

I have a `classstructure` table:

```
create table classstructure (classstructureid number(8,0), classificationid varchar2(25), parent number(8,0));

insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1001, 'FLEET', null);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1002, 'LIGHTDUTYVEHICLE', 1001);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1004, 'MEDIUMDUTYVEHICLE', 1001);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1022, 'ACTIVETRANSPORTATION', null);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1023, 'FACILITYWALKWAY', 1022);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1024, 'TRAIL', 1022);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1085, 'SIDEWALK', 1022);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1091, 'SDWRAMP', 1085);
commit;

select * from classstructure;

CLASSSTRUCTUREID CLASSIFICATIONID              PARENT
---------------- ------------------------- ----------
            1001 FLEET                               
            1002 LIGHTDUTYVEHICLE                1001
            1004 MEDIUMDUTYVEHICLE               1001

            1022 ACTIVETRANSPORTATION                
            1023 FACILITYWALKWAY                 1022
            1024 TRAIL                           1022
            1085 SIDEWALK                        1022
            1091 SDWRAMP                         1085
```

I would like to collapse the records down to hierarchy paths:

```
HIERARCHYPATH
---------------------------
FLEET \ LIGHTDUTYVEHICLE
FLEET \ MEDIUMDUTYVEHICLE 

ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ FACILITYWALKWAY
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ TRAIL
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ SIDEWALK
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ SIDEWALK \ SDWRAMP
```

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps.

```
SQL> select ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(classificationid, ' \ '), ' \ ') hierarchypath
  2  from classstructure
  3  where parent is not null
  4  connect by prior classstructureid = parent
  5  start with parent is null;

HIERARCHYPATH
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FLEET \ LIGHTDUTYVEHICLE
FLEET \ MEDIUMDUTYVEHICLE
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ FACILITYWALKWAY
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ TRAIL
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ SIDEWALK
ACTIVETRANSPORTATION \ SIDEWALK \ SDWRAMP

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```